# Why does ANTLR not parse the entire input?

Tags: parsing, antlr, context-free-grammar

I am quite new to ANTLR, so this is likely a simple question.
I have defined a simple grammar which is supposed to include arithmetic expressions with numbers and identifiers (strings that start with a letter and continue with one or more letters or numbers.)

The grammar looks as follows:

```
grammar while;

@lexer::header {
  package ConFreeG;
}  

@header {
  package ConFreeG;
  
  import ConFreeG.IR.*;
}

@parser::members {
}

arith:
    term
    | '(' arith ( '-' | '+' | '*' ) arith ')'  
    ;
    
term  returns [AExpr a]:    
    NUM
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt($NUM.text);
        a = new Num(n);
    }
    | IDENT
    {
        a = new Var($IDENT.text);
    }
    ;

fragment LOWER : ('a'..'z');
fragment UPPER : ('A'..'Z');
fragment NONNULL : ('1'..'9');
fragment NUMBER : ('0' | NONNULL);
IDENT  : ( LOWER | UPPER ) ( LOWER | UPPER | NUMBER )*;
NUM    : '0' | NONNULL NUMBER*;

fragment NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n';
WHITESPACE  :   ( ' ' | '\t' | NEWLINE )+ { $channel=HIDDEN; };
```

I am using ANTLR v3 with the ANTLR IDE Eclipse plugin. When I parse the expression `(8 + a45)` using the interpreter, only part of the parse tree is generated:

[image]

Why does the second term (a45) not get parsed? The same happens if both terms are numbers.

Comment: Which is your starting rule for parsing?

Comment: I select `arith` as the parsing rule when using the Interpreter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to create a parser rule that has an `EOF` (end of file) token in it so that the parser will be forced to go through the entire token stream.

Add this rule to your grammar:

```
parse
  :  arith EOF
  ;
```

and let the interpreter start at that rule instead of the `arith` rule:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem very intuitive, but it did the trick :)
Thanks!